# Find the name of a link image with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink

I have an html file with links and would like to distinguish if a link is an image or if a link is text. I am using Python 3 and Selenium with Firefox or PhantomJS browser. The goal is to have an automatic procedure to go through several hundred html files and find links with images.

What I do:
I first focus only on one html file.
In a first step I get the names of all images in the html file, where I know that one image is a link and the others are not. I call the images IMAGENAME.

Then I try to derive if one or more of the images is a link. I use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[/img[contains(text(),"'+IMAGENAME[j]+'")]])')
or 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[/img[contains(@src,IMAGENAME[j])]]') 
or 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a/img[contains(@src,IMAGENAME[j])]') 
with j = 0 (image is not a link) and j = 1 (image is a link).
```

In each case I get the same error message, which tells me that the way I call the image must be wrong:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:...
```

When I leave the `//a` part out and use only `//img`, then I get all images without error message.

What am I doing wrong in calling the image in a link? Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I can correctly understand your goal, but `//a[img]` will return you links with images and `//a[not(img)]`- links with text. Note that if you want to use `j` variable in `XPath` you should use `'xpath expression with %s variable' % j`, but not `'xpath expression with j variable'`

Comment: If I remember correctly, `\\a` stands for anchor, whereas you might be looking for `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for the src attribute for all links that contain images, you could use something like:

```
imageLinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a//img")
imageNames = []
for element in imageLinks
    imageNames.add(element.get_attribute("src"))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! That's great! I added ':' after the for loop and used 'append' instead of 'add'.

Comment: Right on! Glad it worked. Sorry about the 'add'. I'm not as familiar with python as I should be.

Comment: still working in 2022 :)